Powershell Regex to delete content between 2 special characters
Using regex I’m trying to delete all content between “\ and until last \”
9123 \fol1\fol2\fol3\fol4\file.txt
I tried
Get-content -path .\src.txt | where-object {$_ -replace (‘[.^\].[(?!.)$.]’,””)
Getting result as
9123 txt
Couldn’t get the right regex to anchor the end special character .
Any help would be really helpful.
Looking to cleanup all contents of directory path and retain only file name
9123 file.txt

please format your question https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

So, -replace '\\.*\\'
